# How do I use query parameters in attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, query-string, mediatr, asp.net-core-routing

I want to use query parameters in my endpoint attributes but I'm not sure how to use them.

I tried this:

```
[HttpPost("fooBar/{version}?amount={amount}&date={date}")]
```

But I get this error instead:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Patterns.RoutePatternException: The literal section '?amount=' is invalid. Literal sections cannot contain the '?' character.
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Patterns.RoutePatternParser.Parse(String pattern)

Or, what's the proper approach to set the query parameters if I want to hit an endpoint that looks like the one above?

Comment: Simple: You don't.

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica what's the proper way then?

Comment: @Euridice01 don't use them in the route template, they will be included once there are matching parameters in the action.

Comment: @Nkosi can you provide an example with the proper way to do this? I am also using MediatR with .net core. Not sure if that changes anything as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't use them in the route template, they will be included once there are matching parameters in the action.

```
//POST fooBar/v2?amount=1234&date=2020-01-06
[HttpPost("fooBar/{version}")]
public IActionResult FooBar(string version, int amount,  DateTime date) {
    //...
}
```

Or explicitly state where they will come from using attributes

```
//POST fooBar/v2?amount=1234&date=2020-01-06
[HttpPost("fooBar/{version}")]
public IActionResult FooBar([FromRoute]string version, [FromQuery]int amount,  [FromQuery]DateTime date) {
    //...
}
```

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)